# onchange event is not working in reactjs component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, onchange

I have the following React component to get the value of an input and then print it in a pdf:

```js
onChange = input => e => {
    this.setState({
        [input]: e.target.value
    });
}
```

and

```html
<input type="text" onChange={this.onChange('prop1')} >
```

its work good if I write something in the input field I can print it in a pdf

but if I pass a dynamic value to the input like this for example:

```html
<input type="text" value={this.state.slices[6].transform === '1' ? '10' : this.state.slices[6].transform.replace('0.','')} onChange={this.onChange('prop1')} >
```

the value will display on the screen but I can't print it in the pdf until I change the text in the input, I think that the `onchange` method is not working in this case.

Comment: `onChange` event only fires after you type something in the input. Setting the value of the `value` attribute won't trigger a `onChange` event.

Comment: Also open up your dev tools console.  See any controlled/uncontrolled component error is there or not.  Thanks.

Comment: @Yousaf so whats event will work in my case please ?

Comment: @rajeshpillai no there is no errors

Comment: When you assign the value to input, no events are triggered but it will be displayed on the screen.  What is your use case as it's not clear from the above code blocks? You may require to handle this in life cycle event of the component (if you can put more clarifications to requirements, it will be more helpful)

Comment: Do you want to set the initial value of the input? If yes, then make the input a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and then use `useEffect` hook to set the initial value.